# Is there a generalization of the Kolmogorov-Chentsov continuity theorem for processes indexed by Banach spaces?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, continuity

If $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a real-valued stochastic process and for all $T>0$, there are $\alpha,\beta,C>0$ with $$\operatorname E\left[\left|X_s-X_t\right|^\alpha\right]\le C\left|s-t\right|^{1+\beta}\;\;\;\text{for all }s,t\in[0,T]\tag1,$$ then $X$ admits a locally $\gamma$-Hölder continuous modification for all $\gamma\in\left(0,\frac\beta\alpha\right)$.

That's a version of the famous Kolmogorov-Chentsov continuity theorem. I've seen generalizations of the theorem to processes indexed by a domain in $\mathbb R^d$, $d\in\mathbb N$. And clearly, we can assume that the process takes values in any Banach space.

> My question is: Are there any generalizations to processes indexed by general (infinite-dimensional) Banach or Hilbert spaces?

If not, are there other criterions to conclude the existence of Hölder continuous modifications for such processes?

Comment: Indexed by "dyadically" separable metric spaces and relevant references in:  "Sample properties of random fields" https://www.math.lsu.edu/cosa/3-3-02[185].pdf